# Калькуляция поля с отбором html

Tags: html

Имеется popup окно со следующим кодом:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="productModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="productModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Закрыть"></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-title">
            Для оформления заказа, заполните, пожалуйста данные
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="productform">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ваше имя" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ваш e-mail" required>
<input type="text" id="two" oninput="mult()" name="quantity" placeholder="укажите желаемое количество" required>
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="сумма" required>
<script> 
function mult() {
    var second = document.getElementById('two').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = second * 9200;
} 
</script>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="phone" placeholder="+ 7 (999) 999-99-99" required>
            <textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="my_btn">Отправить</button>
            <div class="response-output"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Где интересует функция mult:

```
<script> 
function mult() {
    var second = document.getElementById('two').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = second * 9200;
} 
</script>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию таким образом, чтобы: если вводится значение до 10, то умножение на 1000, если от 10 до 50, то умножение на 800 и если от 50 до 100, то на 600?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте условной оператор **if else**

```js
function mult() {
  let coef;
  var second = Number(document.getElementById('two').value);

  if (second < 10) {
    coef = 1000;
  } else if (second >= 10 && second < 50) {
    coef = 800;
  } else if (second >= 50 && second < 100) {
    coef = 600;
  } else {
    alert('Необходимо указать коэффициент');
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById('result').value = second * coef;
}
```

Comment: Сработало. Очень вас благодарю.